# How can I make <li> elements flow left-to-right instead of top-to-bottom?

Tags: html, css

Here are my `<li>` elements. I want them to appear left-to-right instead of top-to-bottom.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**:how to control spacing between each li element and its bachground color and spacing between a element and border of li element?

Answer (score 22):

i think you are looking for

```
li {
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: BTW,how to adjust the spacing between each <li> element?

Comment: @Shore — If you want to control the spacing, you may be better off using `display: inline-block` instead, which allows you to use properties like `margin` and `width` on inline elements.

Comment: Oh,seems `display: inline-block` is not supported by IE.

Comment: No, but IE treats `display: inline` like `display: inline-block`, so you can get the same effect using conditional comments to change what IE sees.  A more serious problem is FF2's lack, which can again be solved, but only using non-validating CSS.  Alternatively, you can switch to the `float` solution and trade these size and position issues for the standard float ones, which can be largely solved with `overflow: auto` on the `<ul>`.

Comment: Not eventhough it worked for me in Firefox it did not in Google Chrome!

Answer (score 7):

There's a few ways.

One way is display:inline as the other posts mention

Another way is float:left;

edit:  more detail!  try this out in a page

```html
<style>
/* style 1 */
div.nav1 ul li
{
  display:inline;

  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;

  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 4em;
}

/* style 2 */
div.nav2 ul li
{
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;

  list-style-type: none;
}
</style>

<h1>using display: inline;</h1>
<div class="nav1">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">inline</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inline blah bla</a></li>
<li><a href="#">i am not so neat on</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inline</a></li>
<li><a href="#">wrapping and I probably</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inline</a></li>
<li><a href="#">need a bit of work and tweaking</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inline</a></li>
<li><a href="#">the "line-height" css property</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inline</a></li>
<li><a href="#">to make me wrap better</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inline</a></li>
<li><a href="#">also notice how i tend to break a line up into .. two.  see?  make your browser narrow.</a></li>
<li><a href="#">inline</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr />

<h1>using float:left;</h1>
<div class="nav2">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">floated left</a></li>
<li><a href="#">i tend to behave</a></li>
<li><a href="#">floated left</a></li>
<li><a href="#">better for wrapping</a></li>
<li><a href="#">floated left</a></li>
<li><a href="#">when the list</a></li>
<li><a href="#">floated left</a></li>
<li><a href="#">reaches the edge of the page</a></li>
<li><a href="#">floated left</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<style>
.nav li {display:inline;}
</style>
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test">test</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The styles should really be in an external style sheet, I just put them on the page for simplicity.

Comment: oh,it works,but could you explain why change li display:inline will hide the bullets of UL?

Comment: Bullets appear only on elements with `display: list-item`, which is the default for <li> elements.  Once you change them to `display: inline`, the browser no longer treats them like list elements and removes the bullets.  The same applies to numbered lists.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the float attribute:

```
.nav ul li{float:left;}
```

Comment: float is prone to cause trouble,I think display:inline is better.

Comment: You'll also probably want to set `.nav ul { overflow: auto; }` to avoid some potential issues with floated elements.

Comment: @Shore — I'm usually more of a fan of `display: inline` myself, but both have their places.  As you noted elsewhere, changing `display` prevents list bulleting/numbering, and there are other subtle differences as well.

Comment: @Shore - Floating is probably best because then the elements are blocks which means you have more control over their styling.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know, that IE does a "step-down" thing when you float list items to the left, and I think that IE is the only browser to do that, all the others keep going straight. To have the list items goes straight across, use "display: inline" in your css instead of "float: left", this should work in all browsers this way. For more in dept explanation, check out this [quick tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/prevent-menu-stepdown/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.nav li  { display: inline }
```

For further details and inspiration, have a look at [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/). They've got tons of excellent tutorials with step-by-step explanations and everything about margin, padding, and browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question after the edit:

```
li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 12px;   /* example spacing */
    margin: 0px 4px;     /* example margin */
}
```

**Edit:** You might want to apply the padding and the display:block to the <a> element so that you can click on the padding as well:

```
li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 4px;     /* example margin */
}
li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 12px;   /* example spacing */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: inline`, like this:

```
li{
    display: inline;
}
```

Or, if you have more lists, you could assign a class to that specific list:

```
<ul class="navbar horizontal">
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

And then style it like:

```
.horizontal{
    display: inline;
}
```